# Syntax errors declaring conditional variables inside YAML jobs

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Trying to edit a function YAML file to include some conditional variables, but whatever I try the file won't seem to run in the pipeline.

The desired variable is an array, which I've tried declaring like this:

```
jobs: 
- deployment:                         Databases
  displayName:                        Deploy Databases in ${{ parameters.stage }}
  environment:                        '${{ parameters.stage }}.${{ parameters.serverName }}'
  timeoutInMinutes:                   2880  

  variables:
    ${{ if eq(parameters.MyParam, True) }}:
      MyArray: [ 'Bar' ]
    ${{ if ne(parameters.MyParam, True) }}:
      MyArray: [ 'Foo' ]

  stages: [ YAML continues ]
```

But when trying to run the pipeline, I get the error:

> A sequence was not expected

I've tried declaring it as a simple string variable instead, but that just gives a different error:

```
  variables:
    ${{ if eq(parameters.MyParam, True) }}:
      MyArray: 'Bar'
    ${{ if ne(parameters.MyParam, True) }}:
      MyArray: 'Foo'
```

> Expected a sequence or mapping. Actual value '$(MyArray)'

Trying this syntax:

```
  variables:
    ${{ if eq(parameters.MyParam, True) }}:
      - name: MyArray
      value: 'Foo'
    ${{ if ne(parameters.MyParam, True) }}:
      - name: MyArray
      value: 'Bar'
```

Yields the error:

> [path] (Line: 9, Col: 5): Expected a mapping
> [path]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Trying this:

variables:
- name: MyArray
${{ if eq(parameters.myParam, True) }}:
value: 'Foo'
${{ if ne(parameters.myParam, True) }}:
value: 'Bar'

Gets me the same errors as my initial attempts.

I've also tried simply declaring a variable without the conditional and that also gives the same original errors. What am I doing wrong here?